# how to read items from file into a list of items and set the properties to the value in the file?

Tags: c#, linq, list, streamreader

Hello I am trying to create a stock log system in c# winforms and i am a bit stuck for ideas on how to read the items back into a list and storing the data into the properties.

I will be reading in from a csv file where each line is 1 item and each property is separated by a comma.

the main Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System.IO;
//using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace stock_list
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private List<item> itemlist = new List<item>((1));

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveitem(Convert.ToInt64(txtStallNumber.Text), Convert.ToInt64(txtStockNumber.Text), txtDescription.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtPaidprice.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txtSoldPrice.Text));
        }

        private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readfromfile();
        }

        private void readfromfile()
        {
            var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"file.csv", Encoding.UTF8, false);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //what todo here??
            }
        }

        private void saveitem(long stallnumberpar, long stocknumberpar, string itemdiscriptionpar, decimal boughtpricepar, decimal soldpricepar, decimal profitorlosspar = 0)
        {
            itemlist.Add(new item { stallnumber = stallnumberpar, stocknumber = stocknumberpar, itemdescription = itemdiscriptionpar, boughtprice = boughtpricepar, soldprice = soldpricepar, profitorloss = soldpricepar - boughtpricepar});
            txtDescription.Clear();
            txtPaidprice.Clear();
            txtSoldPrice.Clear();
            txtStallNumber.Text = "";
            txtStockNumber.Clear();
            txtStallNumber.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Item Saved");
        }

        private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunQueryDescription(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Search Criteria", "Enter Search Criteria", "Default",0,0));
        }

        private void RunQueryDescription(string description)
        {
            //List<item> products = new List<item>((1));
            var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"file.csv", true, Encoding.UTF8);
            item[] productsarr = new item[itemlist.Count];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (item product in itemlist)
            {
                if (product.itemdescription.Contains(description))
                {
                    productsarr[index] = product;
                    index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < productsarr.Length; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(productsarr[i].stallnumber.ToString() + 
                    productsarr[i].stocknumber.ToString() + 
                    productsarr[i].itemdescription.ToString() + 
                    productsarr[i].boughtprice.ToString() + 
                    productsarr[i].soldprice.ToString() + 
                    productsarr[i].profitorloss.ToString());

                writer.Write(productsarr[i].stallnumber.ToString() + "," +
                    productsarr[i].stocknumber.ToString() + "," +
                    productsarr[i].itemdescription.ToString() + "," +
                    productsarr[i].boughtprice.ToString() + "," +
                    productsarr[i].soldprice.ToString() + "," +
                    productsarr[i].profitorloss.ToString());
                writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The items class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

    namespace stock_list
    {
        class item
        {
            public long stallnumber { get; set; }
            public long stocknumber { get; set; }
            public string itemdescription { get; set; }
            public decimal boughtprice { get; set; }
            public decimal soldprice { get; set; }
            public decimal profitorloss { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Example File

```
1,1,Vase,1.00,2.00,1.00
```

Any help will be valued

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Read in the data and then use the [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to parse out the values, then build an instance of `item` and add that item to your list

Comment: can i see some example code please

Comment: Both Grant's and Hossein's answer rely on the same logic as my comment, except they're just using `String.Split` instead. Equally valid method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `File.ReadAllLines` to read the file

```
private List<item> itemlist = new List<item>();
private void readfromfile()
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path");

    foreach (string item in lines)
    {
        var values = item.Split(',');
        itemlist.Add(new item()
        {
            stallnumber = long.Parse(values[0]),
            stocknumber = long.Parse(values[1]),
            itemdescription = values[2],
            //and so on
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting each line on the delimiter (most likely a comma), and then parse out the line and add a new instance of `item` to your list. Something like this should work inside your loop (untested):

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();
var values = line.Split(',');

itemlist.Add(new item { stallnumber = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]), ... });
```