# Access property/field of a class stored as items in a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to access fields `stationName & stationId` located in the class `Station` from main but I am unable to.
Is there a reason for this?

```
public class Station : Line
{
    public string stationName;
    public string stationId;
}

public class Line
{
    public List<Station> line = new List<Station>();
}

class Function
{
    static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(argv[0]))
        {
            string temp;
            Line line = new Line();

            while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
               // error here
               line.line.stationName = line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>I'll eventually make fields to be properties, but it does not change the problem.</sub>

Comment: `line.line.stationName` is a field, make it a property

Comment: @KunalMukherjee changing field to property will not change the problem (and `line.line.stationName` is not a field but rather invalid statement).

Comment: Duplicate answers you exact question as asked, but you likely more interested in [read list items from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430873/how-to-read-items-from-file-into-a-list-of-items-and-set-the-properties-to-the-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with this line

```
line.line.stationName
```

line is a list. You need to access it with index. For example, for accesing stationame

```
line.line[index].stationName
```

In your case, you are adding instances of Station to line. So, you need to

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(argv[0]))
    {
        string temp;
        Line line = new Line();
        while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           line.line.Add(new Station
           {
             stationName = "value you want to assign"
           });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the items in the `List<Station>`. You will need to create a `Station` object in the loop and add it in the `line` collection inside your `Line` class.

You need to write :

```
Line line = new Line();

while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Station s = new Station();
    s.stationName = "stationName";

    line.line.Add(s);
}
```

Better would be use good names of the variables. You can rename it to Stations:

```
public class Line
{
    public List<Station> Stations = new List<Station>();
}
```

So that your code is more easy to read :

```
while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Station station = new Station();
    station.stationName = "stationName";

    line.Stations.Add(station);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your complete program should more precisely be like this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Station
    {
        public string stationName;
        public string stationId;
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public List<Station> stations = new List<Station>();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(argv[0]))
            {
                string temp;
                Line line = new Line();
                int i = 0;

                while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line.stations.Add(new Station
                    {
                        stationName = temp,
                        stationId = (++i).ToString()
                    });
                }

                //For printing
                foreach (var station in line.stations)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(station.stationName);
                    Console.WriteLine(station.stationId);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```